# React - problem updating an array of objects using hooks

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, javascript-objects

I have tried a bunch of approaches but on this, but it's still bugging the hell out of me.   I am using React 17.0.1 in this project.

I have a array of objects formatted like so:

```
 gameNumberFields: [{ name: 'gameNum', placeholder: 'GGG', size: '3', value: '', dataindex: '0' }];
```

For now, there is just one object in the array, but there is always the possibility of more down the road (hence why it's an array).

In the code - this field is pre-populated on initialization - so the "value" of the first index in the array might be something like "123".  I use initialState to make this happen:

`const [gameNumberFields, setGameNumberFields] = useState(scratchTicketFields?.gameNumberFields ?? []);`

When the display is shown to the user - this value is shown to the user in an  field using the defaultValue.

```
        return gameNumberFields.map((field, index) => {
            const ref = React.createRef();
            elemRefs.push(ref);
            return (
                <div className='d-inline-block ticket-number-inputs' key={`game-numbers--${index}`}>
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        id={field.name}
                        data-index={field.dataindex}
                        ref={ref}
                        className='theme-input'
                        placeholder={field.placeholder}
                        size={field.size}
                        maxLength={field.size}
                        defaultValue={field.value}
                        onBlur={(event) => handleGameNumberChange(event, field)}
                        onKeyUp={(event) => autoTab(event, elemRefs)}
                        required
                    />
                    <span className='dash'>&mdash;</span>
                </div>
            );
        });
    }; // end GameIdFieldInputs
```

So far - so good.     The problem I am having is in the onBlur event handler.     For some reason - when the user changes the value to something else -  it always goes back to the old value.

Here is the handler:

```
    const handleGameNumberChange = async (event, field) => {
        // get gameNum from the event target 
        const gameNum = event.target.value;   // say this becomes 999
        
        // do a deep copy of the gameNumberField state.
        let gameIdField = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(gameNumberFields));
        // check that we are changing the right index in the array
        const fieldIndex = gameIdField.findIndex((obj) => obj.name == field.name);
        
        // make a new object changing the value to 999
        let newGameObject = { ...gameIdField[fieldIndex], value: gameNum };
        console.log('newGameObject', newGameObject);
        //NOTE:  At this point the newGameObject is correct and updated with the NEW gameNum of 999
        
        // create a new array and PUSH the new game object onto it
        let newGameIdArray = new Array();
        newGameIdArray.push(newGameObject);
        // Once pushed the array has the OLD game number in it . . . so 123  - WHY?!?!
        console.log('newGameObjectArray', newGameIdArray);
        setGameNumberFields(newGameIdArray); // updates with the 123 game number. . . 
        
    }; // end handleGameNumberChange
```

So in the method, I deep copy the gameNumberFields into a mutable object.   I then update the object with the new gameNumber (from 123 to 999) and all works when I print it out with my console.log for newGameObject.

As soon as I push this object in the new Array -  it changes back to 123!  Can anyone see a flaw in my code here?

When I finally do call setGameNumberFields - it does set the state (I have a useEffect that prints out the values) but again, its always the OLD values.

Any help is welcome and appreciated!

Comment: could you, rather than logging it in the console, which can be unreliable, check the object before setting the state with a debugger?

Comment: @Dean - so your right the console.log is reporting the array is still set to the old value, but the debugger shows that the array actually does have the new value in it. 

However, once the useEffect happens -  the gameNumberFields state is still the old value of 123 and not 999

Comment: yes that confirms it. another assumption, try not deep copying the object, react may not be able to tell the that the object in the array changed and will skip updating the state if it believes the old and new state don't differ

Comment: i meant array not object. but that should not matter actually. since you use it to only find the object. i still think the setting might be skipped by react..perhaps try `[...newGameArray]` in the setter.

Comment: OK, tried a shallow copy, but that didn't make any difference.    Also tried updating my state by doing something like this:

`let updatedGameNumber = gameNumberFields.map(field => { 
   if (gameNum != field.value) {
      return { ...field, value: gameNum };
    }
    return field;
 });
 debugger;   // its fine in the debugger - 999 
 setGameNumberFields(updatedGameNumber);  // reverts back to 123
`

Comment: try the spread syntax from my comment above

Comment: Tried that -  no luck.    

Simplified it to this: 
`let gameIdField = [...gameNumberFields];
 // check that we are changing the right index in the array
 const fieldIndex = gameIdField.findIndex((obj) => obj.name == field.name);
 gameIdField[fieldIndex].value = gameNum;
 setGameNumberFields(gameIdField);
`

The value in gameIdField being set is at 999 however when the useEffect is called - the value in the state remains 123

Comment: at this point it is hard to debug from afar. can you recreate a minimal reproducable example in f.ex. code sandbox?